# Angular 1.6 Component' Template not updating under ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-components, angular1.6

The component is working perfectly fine when used individually. But
If, used under ng-repeat, the DOM is not updated with fetched data

```
.component('viewMore', {
    templateUrl: '../components/clientAllData/clientAllData.html',
    controller: viewMoreCtrl,
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    bindings: {
        icon: '<',
        clientId: '@'
    }....
```

This is how I call the component in ng-repeat:

```
<tr ng-repeat="cfClient in selectedPS.withCF track by $index">
                        <td>{{cfClient.name}}</td>
                        <td>{{cfClient.value | INR}}</td>
                        <td>{{cfClient.revenue | INR}}</td>
                        <td>{{cfClient.linked_cf}}</td>
                        <td>{{cfClient.linked_cfValue}}</td>
                        <td>
                            //view-more is my component
                            <view-more icon="true" client-id="{{cfClient.user_id}}"></view-more>
                            <i class="material-icons">not_interested</i>
                        </td>.....
```

*** The component is able to fetch data using the `client.user_id`, but it is not updating the data inside Component's `view-more` modal-window.

Comment: not sure what you meant by not updating, try change clientId: '@' to clientId: '='

Comment: @CharlieNg ClientID is a binding that takes in client's `user_id' and fetches data from DB for that `user_id` and updates the modal-window with fetched data for the Client.

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by *used under ng-repeat, the DOM is not updated with fetched data*,  can you please add more details?

Comment: @PankajParkar <view-more> is the component used under ng-repeat. When you click view-more component, it fetches data and opens a modal-window with the fetched data. Here, fetching data is working fine, but the modal template is not updated with the fetched data.

Comment: @SomnathPathak I can see that, I'm not sure what exactly isn't working.. add viewMore directive `controller` and `template`

Comment: show us how you handle the data that comes back from DB

Comment: @CharlieNg the data is basically a Javascript Object which contains properties with String and Array data type, something like this:                                                                   
           var test = {'test_name' : 'something', 'test_clients' = [{client1}...], ..}            the ng-repeat is used on suppose 'test_clients' and for each client under that I have used my component and I pass the Client's `client_id` to the component from ng-repeat